# KeyDown not picking up 'Return' key C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

```
    private void idTextEdit_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            SearchButtonClick(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

I have a text box where this code check fires for every single keypress except for the Enter/Return key which for some reason does nothing. The cursor that is active on the textbox disappears, so I'm thinking it changes focus before the keydown event can fire but I'm not sure. How can I get the return key to stop deselecting the box and register as a keypress. Also there is no other code that would set the enter key to have a different functionality and it's a pretty simple one text box screen for testing.

Comment: I've just tried this and my message box gets shown.

Comment: Just checking here: Did you set the event handler to use this code? Also, have you tried placing a breakpoint on your `if` condition before pressing your Enter/Return key to see what the value actually is? Sometimes you'll get a combination of values. If this is the case, you'll want to use bit logic: `if ((e.KeyCode & Keys.Return) == Keys.Return)`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an `AcceptButton` set then you'll get the behaviour you are seeing.

I tried your code with my sample form and it worked as expected.

I then set the `AcceptButton` to one of the buttons and the text box stopped responding to the `Enter`. Setting `AcceptsReturn` on the text box had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `AcceptsEnter` property to `true`

Comment: I've just tried this and it works with `AcceptsReturn` set to false.

Comment: @ChrisF: Might act differently if there's a default button on the form.

Comment: @Chris, I believe if there is an AcceptButton set it will behave differently.

Comment: That was my other thought - I'm still checking it out.

Comment: I've never seen AcceptsEnter before, how would I go about setting this? Is it in the designer as in this.idtextedit.???.AcceptsEnter How do I check or set this?

Comment: As Chris pointed out it is actually called AcceptsReturn - sorry my bad