# C#: Form receives all keypresses except the ENTER key

Tags: c#, .net, forms, keypress

I am designing a custom calculator. Any key pressed on this calculator form should be captured at the 'Form' level. To this end, I've the following code-

```
private void BindControlMouseClicks(Control con)
{
    con.MouseClick += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TriggerMouseClicked(sender, e);
    };
    // bind to controls already added
    foreach (Control i in con.Controls)
    {
        BindControlMouseClicks(i);
    }
    // bind to controls added in the future
    con.ControlAdded += delegate(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        BindControlMouseClicks(e.Control);
    };
}
private void TriggerMouseClicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyPress +=new KeyPressEventHandler(Form1_KeyPress);

    BindControlMouseClicks(this);
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
}

void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    string key;
    switch (e.KeyChar)
    {
        case '\r':
            key = "ENTER";
            break;
        case ' ':
            key = "SPACE";
            break;

        case (char)27:
            key = "ESCAPE";
            break;
        default:
            key = e.KeyChar.ToString();
            break;

    }
    /* Some other code */
}
```

I've set breakpoints and added debug statements in the event handler function `Form1_Keypress`. Surprisingly all relevant keys ( Numerals, alphabets, Escape, Space etc ) hit the callback function except the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. This happens with the <kbd>NUMPAD</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key too.

Any ideas why only the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is being handled differently?

**EDIT**

My form has a bunch of buttons and a textbox. When I place the focus on the textbox, voila, the callback is called for the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key too! But if I put the focus on any of the buttons, no event is generated on <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press. As I've set `KeyPreview` to true, the form must be getting this event irrespective of where the focus is, right?

**EDIT 2**

This happens only when there are buttons on the form and at least on of them has focus on it. If any other control has focus on it, it works just fine. I have not set `AcceptButton` attribute of the form.

Comment: What happens if you hit the enter key? It throws an exception? It does nothing?

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss Nothing happens. No exception or anything.

Comment: Do you have any components like textboxes or buttons in your form? Maybe the enter key is attached to a textbox so it is focusing it or in case of a button, it is trying to activate it.  Also try putting breakpoints in your keypress event handler, debug, hit the enter key and see if something happens.

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss As mentioned in the Qn, the function callback is not getting called when ENTER is pressed. Verified by breakpoints and debug points. But yes, I do have text boxes and buttons on my form. But I want my form to get the keypress before any of the control. Thats why I set KeyPreview to true. Also I've not added any code to attach ENTER key to a specific button or textbox.

Comment: Have you considered using the `AcceptButton` property of the form, to tie to your "calculate" or "=" button, assuming you have such a thing?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318164/enter-key-press-in-c-sharp

Comment: @NeillVerreynne It is not a duplicate. I do not want the keypress to go to the textbox. I have set KeyPreview=true to get all keypresses at the Form level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I describe arises when any of the buttons on my form has focus. So I did these two things -

1. Set `any_button.TabStop = false` initially. This makes sure none of the buttons get focus when the form is launched
2. When we click a button with a mouse, it regains focus. And we end up in the same problem. To solve this, in the Mouse Click Handler, I just pass the focus from the button to some other control. For instance, my form had a menustrip and I just invoked, `menustrip1.Focus()` in the Mouse Click Handler.

Now, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keypresses are caught in `Form_Keypress` handler.

This is a workaround. But I am yet to figure out why <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keypress is not caught by the form when the focus is on a button and not on other controls. I would be glad to have more answers for this Qn

Answer (score 1):

As [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx)([.NET TextBox - Handling the Enter Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558814/net-textbox-handling-the-enter-key)), you can try use `(char)Keys.Return` instead of `\r`:

```
switch (e.KeyChar)
{
    case (char)Keys.Return:
        key = "ENTER";
        break;
```

Also may be there is [some button with AcceptsReturn property set to true on the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103089/keydown-not-picking-up-return-key-c-sharp#answer-6103131)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my problem is, the callback function is not being called at all!!

Comment: I copy-paste your code except BindControlMouseClicks() call and in the end of KeyPress event handler I have `textBox.Text = key`. It works for me - when I press ENTER on the form, textBox receives ENTER text.

Comment: May be you will disclose what kind of work doing BindControlMouseClicks() function?

Comment: I do not want the ENTER key press to go to the textbox. I want to handle ENTER at the form level. Did you check whether ENTER key triggers Form_Keypress()? I shall add code for BindControlMouseCLicks() is my question

Comment: Yes, I checked that Form_Keypress is triggered. I have added BindControlMouseClicks, still works.
Can you create simple project by yourself to be convinced of this simple things works?

Comment: I tested using a simple example. This is happening ONLY when there are buttons on the form. And that too, when the buttons have focus on them. If the focus is on any other element, things work just fine!